# Not able to use @mui/icons-material imports - module not found

Tags: next.js, material-ui

I am no longer able to import icons from `@mui/icons-material` in any local project. The Next.js projects I try to import icons I get errors for `module not found`.

It works on codesandbox but if I download the sandbox and install locally I get `Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/AccountCircleOutlined'` errors when importing icons.

[CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/sandbox/mui-page-layout-w8rp6q)

I'm having this same issue with a large project using mui v5 as well. It can't find the icon imports.

Even if I clone this [project example](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/examples/material-ui-nextjs-pages-router-ts) I am getting the same error importing any icon like import AccountCircleOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AccountCircleOutlined";

Because this is happening on all my projects which are all up to date it's either a local issue or an issue from a recent update. I've tried rolling back versions but haven't been able to fix it yet. Could this be an issue with swc vs webpack in Next.js?

I've deleted `node_modules` and `yarn.lock` and reinstalled but same issues.

My environment:

```
  System:
    OS: macOS 13.5
  Binaries:
    Node: 20.5.0 - /opt/homebrew/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
    npm: 9.8.0 - /opt/homebrew/bin/npm
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 115.0.5790.170
    Edge: 114.0.1823.51
    Safari: 16.6
  npmPackages:
    @emotion/react: ^11.11.1 => 11.11.1
    @emotion/styled: ^11.11.0 => 11.11.0
    @mui/base:  5.0.0-beta.11
    @mui/core-downloads-tracker:  5.14.5
    @mui/icons-material: ^5.14.3 => 5.14.3
    @mui/lab: ^5.0.0-alpha.140 => 5.0.0-alpha.140
    @mui/material: ^5.14.5 => 5.14.5
    @mui/private-theming:  5.14.5
    @mui/styled-engine:  5.13.2
    @mui/styles: ^5.14.5 => 5.14.5
    @mui/system:  5.14.5
    @mui/types:  7.2.4
    @mui/utils:  5.14.5
    @mui/x-data-grid: ^6.11.2 => 6.11.2
    @types/react: ^18.2.20 => 18.2.20
    react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
    react-dom: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
    typescript: ^5.1.6 => 5.1.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is with `@mui/icons-material: 5.14.3`. Downgrading to v5.14.1 fixes the issue.